# Selenium: select an item in combobox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to perform a selenium task on it:

In [this page](http://suvian.in/selenium/1.7button.html), there is a button which i have to click on it and then wait for 10 seconds. I did it like this:
Naviagation to page:

```
base.driver.navigate().to("http://suvian.in/selenium/1.7button.html");
```

Click on button:

```
//base.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3[2]/a"));
        base.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Me"));
```

**This step fails**

Wait for 10 seconds:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(waitTime);
```

**Questions**:

1-it fails on clicking on the button. Although, i asked to find the link both with `xpath`, and `text` it cannot find it?

2-Is my solution correct for make a delay on webdriver's activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dropdown there are 3 options. The first one is `Select`, `Male` is the second. Try

```
select.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using `xpath` locator. 
**Note:** Instead of using `absolute` xpath, use `relative` xpath.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']"))).selectByVisibleText("Male");
```

> OR

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='gender']"))).selectByValue("1");
```